# Disallow user access to microphone

Tags: security

Blacklisting a kernel module would disable the microphone for all users. I have set up a restricted user, who should not be able to use the microphone. The restricted user should, however be able to have sound output. 
Is there a way of reliably disabling the microphone for a restricted user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After experimenting a lot this seems to be the solution:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:user:- /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
```

On my computer, `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c` is the microphone. Blocking write access for a specific user seems to forbid capturing. 
With the above command, I reduce the rights for the user "user" to --- (check with `getfacl /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c`), which does not allow for capturing sound.

Hint: for finding microphones in `/dev/snd/` the `c` for capturing at the end of the name may be an indicator.

**NOTE**: As all changes made to /dev/ will be lost at reboot, as these files are placed in RAM, you would have to additionally add the above command (without `sudo` as `/etc/rc.local` is executed with root rights at boot) to `/etc/rc.local` before the "exit 0" line.